# Does angle between vectors satisfy triangle inequality?

Tags: metric-spaces, vectors, triangle-inequality

For any two unit vectors $a$ and $b$ from $\mathbb{R}^d$, let $θ(a, b)$ be the angle between them, defined as $\cos^{-1}(a^Tb)$. Hence, the angle lies in the range $[0, \pi]$.

Does $θ$ satisfy the triangle inequality, i.e., for any 3 unit vectors $a$, $b$, and $c$, do we have $θ(a, c) ≤ θ(a, b) + θ(b, c)$? I feel that this is true, but I couldn't prove it or find a counterexample.

(If this is true, I would get that $θ$ defines a metric space over unit vectors.)

Comment: Yes, it does.  You get the distance on the sphere.

Comment: @orangeskid Thanks for this insight. I found that we can prove triangle-inequality using https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle#Derivation_of_shortest_paths, but this seems overkill and only works for 3 dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u$, $v$, $w$ three unit vectors in an euclidean space. To show that

$$\arccos \langle u, v\rangle + \arccos \langle v, w\rangle \ge \arccos \langle u, w\rangle$$

Denote the above angles by $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$. Consider the [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix) associated to $u$, $v$, $w$. We know that this matrix is positive semidefinite, so its determinant is $\ge 0$. But now we [calculate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Det%5B%20%7B%7B1%2CCos%5B%CE%B1%5D%2CCos%5B%CE%B2%5D%7D%2C%7BCos%5B%CE%B1%5D%2C1%2CCos%5B%CE%B3%5D%7D%2C%7BCos%5B%CE%B2%5D%2CCos%5B%CE%B3%5D%2C1%7D%7D%5D)

$$\left | \begin{matrix} 1 & \cos \alpha & \cos \beta \\ \cos \alpha & 1 & \cos \gamma \\ \cos \beta & \cos \gamma & 1\end{matrix} \right |= 4 \sin p \sin(p-\alpha) \sin (p-\beta) \sin (p-\gamma)$$

where $p = \frac{\alpha + \beta + \gamma}{2}$.

This shows that $p- \max ( \alpha, \beta, \gamma) \ge 0$, which is what we need. It is also easy to see when we have equality: the vectors must be linearly dependent.

Comment: How did you come up with this proof? I could have never thought of something like this.

Comment: @Eklavya Sharma: so there are 4 linear inequalities between $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ that make the above determinant $\ge 0$ ( assume for starter they are in $[-\pi, \pi]$), that get them lying in a tertrahedron.  I've met this before.